# how can i reuse parent component and give children props in react?

Tags: reactjs

```
const Group = ()=>{

const someAction = ()=>{

}

return <Animal action = {someAction}/><
}
```

My Code looks like this, and I want to reuse this Group function component and change only Animal component,

```
const Group = ()=>{

const someAction = ()=>{

}

return <Fish action = {someAction}/><
}
```

```
const Group = ()=>{

const someAction = ()=>{

}

return <Dog action = {someAction}/><
}
```

All props that is given to Fish, Dog component is same.
So I want to reuse Group component Like this

```
<div>
  <Group component={<Fish/>} />
  <Group component={<Dog/>}/>
</>
```

But the problem is props that is given to child component.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
const Group = ({ component }) => {
  const Animal = component
  const someAction = () => {}
  return <Animal action={someAction} />
}
```

And then use it like so:

```js
<>
  <Group component={Fish} />
  <Group component={Dog} />
</>
```